# GWT: Cannot keep control of Window anymore once I close its pop-up

Tags: javascript, gwt, browser, window, reload

My app is:

1. Doing something on main window
2. Opening a new window to do something there

   ```java
   Window.open(userInfo.signInURLs.get("Google"), "Google", null);
   ```
3. Closing that new window

   ```java
   native public static void close()/*-{ $wnd.close(); }-*/;
   ```
4. Trying to reload the main window

   ```java
   Window.Location.reload();
   ```

Everything is fine until I close the new windows. I cannot keep control of the main window anymore. Actions I run are never executed. Any ideas?

Comment: can you add more code? like the whole implementation of opening window and closing window? Also `Window.Location.reload()` should be in all lowercase.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to edit my post with the simplest case where this fails. Anyway I can tell you that the issue is this simple: when I open a new window (step 3), I cannot keep control of the old one (step 5). The Window.Location.reload() is a GWT function and I believe has to be written like that.

Comment: Is the new window, a child of the old window (like a modal?) or is it a completely new window?

Comment: It is a completely new window (Window.open function). Could work with a modal, but I am not sure how to do that on GWT. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you work with GWT you want as faw page reload as possible. If you load data you make partial page reloads using ajax. The approach you have chosen is not very feasible. With window.location.reload - you make a whole page reload. Don't do that.

You should use a modal window - in gwt that is very simple.
Use DialogBox, that makes a modal Window.

http://examples.roughian.com/index.htm#Widgets~DialogBox